# Pydbus more notifications same time handling

Tags: python-3.x, glib, dbus

I would like to receive sensor data from BLE devices by notifications using pydbus.
I am using GLib with main loop
Linked a part of my code:

```
def sensor1_handler(iface, prop_changed, prop_removed):
    if 'Value' in prop_changed:
       
        """Handle values"""
       
def sensor2_handler(iface, prop_changed, prop_removed):
    if 'Value' in prop_changed:
       """Handle values"""

sensor1=bus.get("org.bluez", "/org/bluez/hciX/dev_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX/serviceYYYY/charYYYY")
sensor2=bus.get("org.bluez", "/org/bluez/hciX/dev_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX/serviceYYYY/charYYYY")
sensor1.onPropertiesChanged = sensor1_handler
sensor2.onPropertiesChanged = sensor2_handler

sensor2.StartNotify()
sensor1.StartNotify()
```

When I would like to receive the notifications, the two signals arrive almost the same time and only one (the first arrived notification) Notification Callback function runs.

How could I solve this problem? I was thinking on a message queue.

**EDIT:**

sensor1 function:

```
def sensor1_handler(iface, prop_changed, prop_removed):
    if 'Value' in prop_changed:
        temperatureLSB = prop_changed['Value'][1]
        temperatureMSB = prop_changed['Value'][0]
        humidityLSB = prop_changed['Value'][3]
        humidityMSB = prop_changed['Value'][2]
        temperature = temperatureLSB | (temperatureMSB << 8)
        humidity = humidityLSB | (humidityMSB << 8)
        print(-45+175*(temperature/(pow(2,16)-1)))
        print(100*(humidity/(pow(2,16)-1)))
```

sensor2 function:

```
def sensor2_handler(iface, prop_changed, prop_removed):
    if 'Value' in prop_changed:
        iaqLSB = prop_changed['Value'][1]
        iaqMSB = prop_changed['Value'][0]
        iaq = iaqLSB | (iaqMSB << 8)
        print(iaq)
```

sensor2 data sent before sensor1 so sensor2 data arrives first. The two data arrives from the same device, I did not add the other devices yet.

Comment: Your explanation of what is happening does not sound complete. Property change callbacks don't just disappear because there was another property change at the same time. Are you sure your first callback handler isn't blocking?

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: I know it is not the problem you came here for but going from bytes to an integer can be done more efficiently with `int.from_bytes` e.g. `temperature = int.from_bytes(prop_changed['Value'][0:2], byteorder='little', signed=True)`

Comment: Not a problem :)
It makes my code more efficient so thank you
The problem is I don't understand why the second callback function is not called and why it is just not delayed

Comment: @AndrewS, I'll take a look the weekend if someone hasn't come back with an answer. Nothing obvious comes to mind as to why it doesn't work. Just need a bit of time to create a trial to prove it for myself

Comment: Thank you.
In the meantime i will keep trying to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for every help!

After many attemptions, I've noticed the problem was on my server side.
The two sensor data was sent from one device with ~10ms difference and the message sending was not in Notification mode but Indication.

I have not noticed it before, because I have sent only 1 sensor data with 2 seconds difference but problem came when I was trying to send 2 messages almost simultaneously.

After setting it to Notification, the server could send messages rapidly (did not need acknoledgement).

I know this error was not caused by pydbus in the end, but by my fault. I hope that if someone finds a similar problem, they should check the sender (server) side as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful or not, but I have not been able to reproduce the issue. I two BBC micro:bits and have subscribed to notifications from Button A on both of them. I have been mashing the buttons as close to the same time as I can and both have appeared without issue.

Below is the code I used for the experiment. It is slightly longer than is maybe ideal as an example but I created it by modifying an existing example. It shouldn't need too much modification to run with your device and see if you have the same issue.

```py
from time import sleep
from gi.repository import GLib

import pydbus

bus = pydbus.SystemBus()

mngr = bus.get('org.bluez', '/')

DEV1 = 'DC:DB:16:6B:8C:5F'
DEV2 = 'DE:82:35:E7:43:BE'

def get_characteristic_path(dev_path, uuid):
    mng_objs = mngr.GetManagedObjects()
    for path in mng_objs:
        chr_uuid = mng_objs[path].get('org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1', {}).get('UUID')
        if path.startswith(dev_path) and chr_uuid == uuid:
           return path

class MyRemoteDevice:
    CHAR_UUID = 'e95dda90-251d-470a-a062-fa1922dfa9a8'

    def __init__(self, mac_addr):
        device_path = f"/org/bluez/hci0/dev_{mac_addr.replace(':', '_')}"
        self.device = bus.get('org.bluez', device_path)

        # Placeholder for characteristic details
        self.characteristic = None

    def _get_gatt_details(self):
        char_path = get_characteristic_path(self.device._path, MyRemoteDevice.CHAR_UUID)
        self.characteristic = bus.get('org.bluez', char_path)


    def connect(self):
        self.device.Connect()
        while not self.device.ServicesResolved:
            sleep(0.25)
        self._get_gatt_details()

    def disconnect(self):
        self.characteristic.StopNotify()
        self.device.Disconnect()

    def read(self):
        return self.characteristic.ReadValue({})

    def write(self, new_value):
        self.characteristic.WriteValue(new_value, {})

    def _notify_handler(self, iface, prop_changed, prop_removed):
        value = prop_changed.get('Value', [])
        if value:
            print(f'{self.device.Address} is {int.from_bytes(value, byteorder="little")}')

    def start_notify(self):
        self.characteristic.onPropertiesChanged = self._notify_handler
        self.characteristic.StartNotify()


my_first_dev = MyRemoteDevice(DEV1)
my_second_dev = MyRemoteDevice(DEV2)

my_first_dev.connect()
my_second_dev.connect()

print(my_first_dev.read())
print(my_second_dev.read())

my_first_dev.start_notify()
my_second_dev.start_notify()

mainloop = GLib.MainLoop()

try:
    mainloop.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    mainloop.quit()
    my_first_dev.disconnect()
    my_second_dev.disconnect()
```

Here is an example output from one of runs. It seemed reliable for me.

```
(venv) pi@raspberrypi:~/stack_overflow $ python two_notifications.py 
[0]
[0]
DC:DB:16:6B:8C:5F is 1
DE:82:35:E7:43:BE is 1
DC:DB:16:6B:8C:5F is 2
DE:82:35:E7:43:BE is 2
DC:DB:16:6B:8C:5F is 0
DE:82:35:E7:43:BE is 0
DC:DB:16:6B:8C:5F is 1
DE:82:35:E7:43:BE is 1
DC:DB:16:6B:8C:5F is 0
DE:82:35:E7:43:BE is 0
DC:DB:16:6B:8C:5F is 1
DE:82:35:E7:43:BE is 1
DC:DB:16:6B:8C:5F is 2
DE:82:35:E7:43:BE is 2
DE:82:35:E7:43:BE is 0
DC:DB:16:6B:8C:5F is 0
DE:82:35:E7:43:BE is 1
DC:DB:16:6B:8C:5F is 1
DE:82:35:E7:43:BE is 2
DC:DB:16:6B:8C:5F is 2
DC:DB:16:6B:8C:5F is 0
DE:82:35:E7:43:BE is 0
```

It was done in a bit of hurry so let me know if anything isn't clear.