# Connecting to multiple ESP32 Ble servers lowers datarate

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I have an issue with connecting to multiple esp32 ble servers.

Each esp32 does the following:

- Declare a Service and 2 Characteristics with **Notify** property
- Set the value to characteristics (max 20 bytes in size)
- When a client is connected start notifying.

On my PC side I'm using Python3 with bluepy to communicate to one or more esp32 devices.
If i connect only to **one device** I can receive data at about **250 Hz for** Characteristic 1 and **100 Hz** for Characteristic 2.

The problem arises when I connect to **two or more devices.** In this case **only one device transmits at the rate mentioned above** and all the other devices transmit very slowly, some may fall below **10 Hz**.

### Code for ESP32

publishBLEdata() is used to send a 20-byte array.

```cpp
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLE2902.h>

#include "esp_bt_main.h"
#include "esp_bt_device.h"

BLEServer *pServer = NULL;
BLECharacteristic * p_TX_FSR_Characteristic;
BLECharacteristic * p_TX_IMU_Characteristic;
bool deviceConnected = false;
bool oldDeviceConnected = false;

#define SERVICE_UUID           "42426001-0bfe-4adb-aefb-5b5708b77691" // UART service UUID
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_TX_FSR "42426002-0bfe-4adb-aefb-5b5708b77691"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_TX_IMU "42426003-0bfe-4adb-aefb-5b5708b77691"

#define BLE_MAX_DATA_SIZE 20



class MyServerCallbacks: public BLEServerCallbacks {
    void onConnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
      deviceConnected = true;
    };

    void onDisconnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
      deviceConnected = false;
    }
};


bool initBluetooth()
{
  if (!btStart()) {
    Serial.println("Failed to initialize controller");
    return false;
  }

  if (esp_bluedroid_init() != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.println("Failed to initialize bluedroid");
    return false;
  }

  if (esp_bluedroid_enable() != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.println("Failed to enable bluedroid");
    return false;
  }

}


void initBLEService() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  initBluetooth();
  const uint8_t* point = esp_bt_dev_get_address();

  // Set device name to containe the last 2 values of the MAC address
  char bt_name[13] = {};
  sprintf(bt_name, "ESP32_%02X%02X", (int)point[4], (int)point[5]);

  // Create the BLE Device
  BLEDevice::init(bt_name);

  // Create the BLE Server
  pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  pServer->setCallbacks(new MyServerCallbacks());

  // Create the BLE Service
  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);

  // Create a BLE Characteristics
  p_TX_FSR_Characteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                                        CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_TX_FSR,
                                        BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY
                                    );

  p_TX_IMU_Characteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                                        CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_TX_IMU,
                                        BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY
                                    );

  p_TX_FSR_Characteristic->addDescriptor(new BLE2902());
  p_TX_IMU_Characteristic->addDescriptor(new BLE2902());

  // Start the service
  pService->start();

  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(SERVICE_UUID);
  pAdvertising->setScanResponse(true);
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x06);  // functions that help with iPhone connections issue
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x12);

  BLEDevice::startAdvertising();


  Serial.print(bt_name);
  Serial.println("\t Waiting a client connection to notify...");

}

void publishBLEdata(uint8_t* txValue, size_t length, char mode, uint16_t delay_ns = 3300)
{

    BLECharacteristic * characteristic;

    switch (mode)
    {
    case 'f':
        characteristic = p_TX_FSR_Characteristic;
        break;

    case 'i':
        characteristic = p_TX_IMU_Characteristic;
        break;

    default:
        characteristic = p_TX_FSR_Characteristic;
        break;
    }

    if (deviceConnected) {

        characteristic->setValue(txValue, length);
        characteristic->notify();
        delayMicroseconds(delay_ns);

    }

    // disconnecting
    if (!deviceConnected && oldDeviceConnected) {
        delay(500); // give the bluetooth stack the chance to get things ready
        pServer->startAdvertising(); // restart advertising
        Serial.println("start advertising");
        oldDeviceConnected = deviceConnected;
    }
    // connecting
    if (deviceConnected && !oldDeviceConnected) {
        // do stuff here on connecting
        oldDeviceConnected = deviceConnected;
    }
}
```

### Python code

Connect to a specific MAC address, and for every notification activate the callback function which unpacks and displays the data. For every new esp32 device that I want to connect I run a separate python script.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from bluepy import btle

class MyDelegate(btle.DefaultDelegate):
    def __init__(self, handle_fsr, handle_imu):
        btle.DefaultDelegate.__init__(self)
        self.handle_fsr = handle_fsr
        self.handle_imu = handle_imu

        self.fsr_datatype = 'B'     # 1 byte unsigned char
        self.fsr_num_bytes = 1
        self.fsr_num_values = 8
        self.imu_datatype = 'h'     # 2 byte integer
        self.imu_num_bytes = 2
        self.imu_num_values = 10

    def handleNotification(self, cHandle, data):
        if cHandle == self.handle_fsr:
            fsr_decoded = list()
            for i in range(self.fsr_num_values):
                data_raw = data[(i*self.fsr_num_bytes):(self.fsr_num_bytes + i*self.fsr_num_bytes)]
                val, = struct.unpack(self.fsr_datatype, data_raw)

                fsr_decoded.append(val)

            print(fsr_msg)

        if cHandle == self.handle_imu:
            imu_decoded = list()
            imu_msg = IMU()
            for i in range(self.imu_num_values):
                data_raw = data[(i*self.imu_num_bytes):(self.imu_num_bytes + i*self.imu_num_bytes)]
                val, = struct.unpack(self.imu_datatype, data_raw)
                imu_decoded.append(val)

            print(imu_decoded)


mac_addr = "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"

service_uuid = btle.UUID("42426001-0bfe-4adb-aefb-5b5708b77691")
fsr_uuid = btle.UUID("42426002-0bfe-4adb-aefb-5b5708b77691")
imu_uuid = btle.UUID("42426003-0bfe-4adb-aefb-5b5708b77691")


try:
    p = btle.Peripheral(mac_addr)

    ch_fsr = p.getCharacteristics(uuid=fsr_uuid)[0]
    ch_imu = p.getCharacteristics(uuid=imu_uuid)[0]
    handle_fsr = ch_fsr.getHandle()
    handle_imu = ch_imu.getHandle()

    # Enable notifications
    p.writeCharacteristic(handle_fsr+1, b"\x01\x00")
    p.writeCharacteristic(handle_imu+1, b"\x01\x00")

    p.setDelegate( MyDelegate(handle_fsr, handle_imu) )
except Exception as e:
    raise e


run = True
while run:
    try:
        if p.waitForNotifications(1.0):
            # handleNotification() was called
            continue

        print("{} Waiting...".format(namespace))

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        run = False
        p.disconnect()
```

And that's about it.

Can anyone please help me figure out what I'm missing?
Are there any advertising parameters missing on the server such that multiple devices don't interfere with each other? Or maybe there's something missing in the Python script (client side).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bluetooth LE is not a high speed transmissions protocol. It has other priorities. If multiple devices transmit at a high rate the chance of collisions will raise more than linearly. Usually Bluetooth LE is used for values that update with longer intervals (>1s).

Comment: So a solution would be just to lower the transmission rate? I already tried to lower in to 100 Hz but it exhibits the same behaviour. Namely only one device transmits at the desired rate and all the other are worse. This leads me to belive that maybe there's some setting like advertising on different channels maybe.

Comment: I suspect the issue is on the Python client side implementation. I would suggest running it asynchronously in a single script and let the event loop handle the notifications coming in from different devices. There is any example of this at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63944132/7721752